# How do we express a person who can not see anything in the dark and moves by feeling things around him with his hands?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Say a man is blindfolded and is trying to get to a place. He can not see anything and he has to move by feeling things around him with his hands.

I found this verb "**grope**".

For example, *[He groped his way up the staircase in the dark.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/grope_1?q=groping)*

Is  "**grope**" a common word to express that meaning in everyday English? or do we have a more common term for it?

Comment: "groping around in the dark" is a very common idiomatic way to say this: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=groping+around+in+the+dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Grope' is the most usual way of expressing this, also we can say that someone 'feels their way in the dark'. We usually only use these when someone who is able to see is unable to do so temporarily, for example because it has suddenly become dark, or they have been blindfolded. People who are blind are usually good at finding their way around.